# How to Dynamically adding HTTP endpoint to load data into azure data lake by using Azure Data Factory and the REST api is cookie autheticated

Tags: azure, rest, session-cookies, azure-data-factory, data-pipeline

I am trying to dynamically add/update linked service REST based on certain trigger/events to consume a RESP API to be authenticated using cookie which provides telemetry data. This telemetry data will be stored in Data Lake Gen2 and then will use Data Bricks to move to secondary data storage/SQL Server.

Have someone tried this? I am not able to find the cookie based Auth option while adding the linked service REST.

Also how to create data pipes dynamically or to have the parameters of the rest api to be dynamic ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, unfortunately this is not possible using Azure data factory native components/activities. For now at least, you cannot get access to the response cookies from a web request in data factory. Someone has put a feature request for this or something that might help, see [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/35857762-support-response-headers-and-cookies-as-output-fro)

It might be possible to do this via an Azure function to get/save the cookie and then send it as part of a following request. I had a similar problem but resorted to using Azure functions for all of it, but I guess you could just do the authentication part with a function! ;-)

**EDIT: update**

Actually, after I wrote this I went back to check if this was still the case and looks like things have changed. There now appears (never seen this before) in the web response output, a property called "ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders" and as you can see there is property for the "Set-Cookie"

See example below:-

[image]